# beamer presentation for mathematicians

Tags: beamer, lists, itemize

I am using the following code for my presentation:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\mode<beamer>{%
\usetheme[hideothersubsections,
right,width=22mm]{Goettingen}
}
\title{Math}
\author[Mister X]{X}
\institute{University}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=20mm]{USTL}}
\date{January 15, 2012}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<handout:0>
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

But I am having troubles using environments like `itemize`. It is a mathematical presentation, It is a long time ago I used a `beamer` presentation.

EDIT: I know the problem, when compiling I should close the "pdf file".

Comment: Where is your question? What do you mean with "trouble"?

Comment: An example of where you find troubles is necessary.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, but I know the problem (I have edited the post).

Comment: There should be any need to close your `pdf` file. What makes you think so? How do you produce your `pdf` file?

Comment: I do two things:
1) compile the latex file while the pdf file is open => error: I get a new latex file which gives me weird information.
2) I first close the pdf file, no problems.